# Folder redirection: why domain administrator can't access folder?

Tags: windows-server-2008, folder-redirection

I setup-ped folder redirection in a windows server 2008 environment. 
The problem is that Domain Admins can't access 'My Documents' user folder, so i can't also backup folder. 
How is possible ? 
Is it correct ? 
How to do to correctly setup folder redirection allowing user admin access ?

Thanks

Comment: Why is your Domain Admins group backing up anything? You should use a service account for backups with only the user rights needed to backup data (Backup Operators group membership).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't enable the option that grants the user exclusive rights to the folder. We don't enable this on ANY of the redirects (that includes application data - makes it much easier to do stuff like generating signatures).

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Agreed - stupid setting!

Comment: Just a note for anyone who may not be aware: Unticking that box will affect NEW folders but doesn't affect EXISTING foloders.